# Is it true that $X\stackrel{\imath}{\hookrightarrow} X\sqcup Y\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} Z$ is a quotient map?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be topological spaces and $f:X\sqcup Y\longrightarrow Z$ a quotient map. Is it true that the composition $$X\stackrel{\imath}{\hookrightarrow} X\sqcup Y\stackrel{f}{\longrightarrow} Z$$
is a quotient map?

Comment: Check that $\imath$ is quotient map and the composition of quotient maps are also quotient map.

Comment: Quotient maps must be surjective.

Comment: Ok, the domain of the inclusion must be a saturated open set to result in a quotient..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=\{a,b\}$ and $Y=\{c,d\}$ with the topology given by the open sets $\{a\}$ and $\{d\}$. Identify $a$ with $c$ and $b$ with $d$. Then $q$ is injective on $X$, so it would be a homeomorphism onto $Z$ if it were a quotient on $X$. But $Z$ is indiscrete since the preimages are $\{a,c\}$ and $\{b,d\}$, and none of them is open.

There are, however, simple cases where the restriction of $q:\sqcup X_i\to Z$ restricts to a quotient map on every subfamily of $(X_i)_i$. For example, if $(X_i,x_i)$ are pointed spaces, then $q:\sqcup_i X_i\to \bigvee_i X_i$ is also a quotient on $\sqcup_j Y_j$, for $\{Y_j\mid j\}\subset\{X_i\mid i\}$, so $\bigvee_j Y_j$ is a subspace of $\bigvee_i X_i$.